# When selecting a dropdown item how do I get a specific list of questions to appear .net / html

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-select, cascadingdropdown

Please don't give me the outright answer, I'm a newb and I'm stuck - just need pointed in the right direction.

I have a dropdown with 4 values (in html) and I would like a list of questions to pop up for each of the values in the drop down.e.g dropdown item 1 = question list 1; dropdown item 2 = question list 2.

My search keeps pointing me to a table pulled from sql, but I don't want that, I only want a form that is submitted to sql after the specific list of questions is answered.

I'm building this in visual studio so will need .net help

Thank you so much smart people!

Comment: What framework are you using to produce your HTML? ASP.NET MVC? WebForms?

Comment: Apologies, I thought that was in there. asp.net

Comment: ASP.NET has different technologies for web applications. Are you using MVC or WebForms?

Comment: I'm going to go with web forms - tbh I've only written the html/and built the sql backend for my page, I haven't really started the asp.net piece for actions. Looking for a good starting point for this type of functionality. I want to learn it on my own though so I remember for next time.

Comment: So these are just static options? You're just looking for how to create a dropdown list in HTML? Or are you using a web control that you plan to write C# code to access in code-behind?

Comment: The logic is this:
I have a drop down with four items, I want a separate list of questions to show on the site for each item that you can select in the drop down. I will take the answers from the questions and save them to sql. I guess to start I'm looking for some good high level logic advise. Like do I build the question list in HTML then use asp.net to call each question list tied to each drop down item? and how do I tie a list of questions to each specific item in the dropdown?

Comment: Those are some pretty broad questions, which aren't very well suited to StackOverflow's Q/A format. There are a lot of correct ways you could approach it. For example, you might consider a wizard-like interface where the user selects an answer from the dropdown, clicks "next", and is presented with a different page depending on which answer she chose.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to make a standard HTML select list, it looks like this:

```html
    <label> Choose your first question
    <select name="questionList1">
        <option value="question1">What is your name?</option>
        <option value="question2">What is your quest?</option>
        ...
    </select>
    </label>
```

If you're using a DropDownList control in WebForms, you can [follow these instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w384x40a.aspx) to add static values to the option list.

Comment: The answer to my own question was to create multiple asp:Panels and then use an if else statement to set the panels to visible true or false based on the dropdown value. Thanks for the support!